# Fatal error in ../../src/api.h, line 499. Check failed: entered_contexts_.length() == 0

Tags: c++, v8

I am a beginner with v8. Executing js script withing a shell context. Works fine when the v8 build in x86. 
Problem occurs when building in x64. The `v8:Locker` destructuring before `Scope`

Here, what I am doing

```
v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
v8::Locker lock(isolate);
v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
v8::Local < v8::Context > context = ...
context->Enter();
```

Core dumped when executing a script for `entered_contexts_.length()` being 1.

```sh
# Fatal error in ../../src/api.h, line 499
# Check failed: entered_contexts_.length() == 0.
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

    ./LIB64/libv8_libbase.so(+0x15923) [0x7f1869f68923]
    ./LIB64/libv8_libbase.so(V8_Fatal+0xdd) [0x7f1869f63c8d]
    ./LIB64/libv8.so(+0x1f41cf) [0x7f186745a1cf]
    ./LIB64/libv8.so(+0xa747fb) [0x7f1867cda7fb]
    ./LIB64/libv8.so(v8::Locker::~Locker()+0x4a) [0x7f1867cda73a]
```

What could cause problem in x64 , where same code works in x86?
Also how could I debug the context properly with shared library libv8.so source?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you need to extract and provide a [mcve] as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should behave the same on all platforms. Maybe one of the builds is a Debug build and the other is not?

Generally, for debugging, you need a Debug build and a debugger. Whether `libv8.so` is a shared library or not doesn't make a difference, as long as it's been compiled in Debug mode. (I debug shared `libv8.so` all the time.)

When asking for help, besides providing a reproducible example, it would be helpful if you specified the V8 version that you're using. In the current version, the string "entered_contexts_.length" never shows up in api.h, so I know you're using an older version, but I don't know which.

All that said, a wild guess at the problem itself: given that you do `context->Enter()`, and then get a failure because `entered_contexts_.length() == 1`, maybe try exiting the context when you're done with it?

Comment: V8 version number is 5. Exiting the context gives another error  

Fatal error in ../../src/api.h, line 345
# Check failed: allow_empty_handle || that != __null

Comment: There are hundreds of 5.x.y.z version numbers. -- Please post a complete reproducible example. And please give debugging a try yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
V8 version is 5.9.0. 
I have been debugging into the libv8.so using gdb from my binary. 
Getting the error from #0 api.cc:10082:HandleScopeImplementer::FreeThreadResources(), #1 api.h:497:void Free().

I am trying to make a reproducible example, but I don't know how to make one from this big project. This project using V8 to execute a js script using shell context almost exactly like [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/5.8/samples/shell.cc#80). Only difference is the v8::Locker usage in my case.

Comment: If I exit or remove the context->Enter(), then it goes from v8::Script::Compile like this: Utils::ApiCheck at api.h:121 => Utils::OpenHandle at api.h:345 => V8_Fatal (file=0x7ffff5ef27ef "../../src/api.h", line=345, format=0x7ffff5ef2537 "Check failed: %s.") at ../../src/base/logging.cc:51 (Check failed: allow_empty_handle || that != __null) => to immediate crash

Comment: See https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/5.9/test/cctest/test-lockers.cc for examples how to use `v8::Locker`s.

Comment: After using a `Persistent` context it works now. And context is used among multiple threads. But some time it's giving `double free or corruption (fasttop) in /lib64/libc.so.6`. And same code is working perfectly on x86 though.

Comment: That probably means that you have a race condition somewhere, and/or are doing something unsafe with your threads.